# Tailor recently viewed list views by profile

Tags: lightning, list-view

Is it possible to change the recently viewed list view displayed fields based on profiles?

I want Profile X to see the default recently viewed fields.

I Profile Y to see a different set of fields on the same recently viewed list view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is not possible at this moment. The Recently viewed List View is controlled by the Object's Search Layout which only can contain 1 version for that object. In classic the controller was the Tab element:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_recent_records_list_lex.htm&type=5

There are several ideas is in the IdeaExchange around Recently Viewed List limitations:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpRoAAK
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CSLkQAO

Hope I had a better answer for you.